# What does this console warning mean for my constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a table view, and set up constraints inside the cell... i am getting one constraint error which I do not understand. This is the console print:

```
2019-07-08 01:10:56.377538-0400 TableCellDynamicHeight[5827:393085] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x2835000a0 _UILayoutGuide:0x135e164f0.height == 20   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x283500000 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x135e164f0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x135e16310 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283517e80 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x135e164f0]-(0)-[UITableView:0x13682e800]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2835001e0 V:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x13682e800]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x135e16310 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x283517e80 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x135e164f0]-(0)-[UITableView:0x13682e800]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

And this is what my viewController and constraints look like:

[image]

Comment: try delete top constraint of tableview and again give it to the safearea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically tells you that your constraints are conflicting and it has to automatically remove 1 of them.

Lets say you have a view that is of 40 height. Then you put a view inside it and tell it to be 10 from top and 20 height and 0 from bottom. This will cause it to tell you that 1 constraint is wrong and has to be removed to work. as you order it to be of height 30 while the height is actually 40.

Another thing is if you actually would have 10 to bottom in the case above. This would also create a conflict as the view already know that it is 10 to the bottom, which means you basically tell the compiler its 10 to the bottom Twice